# How to find input tag od div 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if we have div like this

```
<div id="1">
    <input type="text" />
    <div id="2"></div>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <div id="4">
        <input type="text"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

now if i want to jump from div of id=4 to input tag of `<div id="1">`
using parent child relationship how can i jump to that particular input tag.
Please help

Thanks..

Comment: Please help us understanding the Question. It seems to be missing everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#4').parent().prev().children('input:first')
```

Of course this assumes that div#1 is always the previous sibling of div#3, like you have in the example.

Comment: +1 but please take note that id's should not start with numbers... ;)

Comment: Good point. I would not do that myself, but wanted to use his example data exactly like he had it.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("4").childNodes[0].

Though if you are using jquery it would be something like:

$("#4").children(":input")

Answer (score 0):

IDs can't start with a number, so I change your code to:

```
<div id="id1">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="id2"></div>
</div>
<div id="id3">
  <div id="id4">
    <input type="text"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

So, that makes it:

```
$("#id4").parents("body").children("div:first").children("input")
```

Another, shorter version:

```
$("#id4").parents("body").find('input')
```

Or the fast way:

```
$("input:first")
```

Comment: in HTML4 yes.. in HTML5 it can be any string as long as it's unique.